# Execute a method after delay on time only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm using this method to call another method every 60 seconds:

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null, 
                              new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
```

It is possible to call this method only once after delay of 1 millisecond?

Comment: You could always set the second TimeSpan to null. Not an ideal solution, but it would work.

Comment: You could stop the timer on the called method using the sender object

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming this is a `System.Threading.Timer`, from the documentation for the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ah1h85ch.aspx)'s final parameter:

> *period*
>   The time interval between invocations of the methods referenced by callback. Specify negative one (-1) milliseconds to disable periodic signaling.

So:

```
Timer updateTimer = new Timer(testt, null,
                              TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1),   // Delay by 1ms
                              TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)); // Never repeat
```

Is a delay of 1ms really useful though? Why not just execute it immediately? If you're really just trying to execute it on a thread-pool thread, there are better ways of achieving that.

Comment: ERROR: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label8' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. - when trying to display something on the Form.

Comment: @TomeeNS: I suspect you're using the wrong kind of Timer then.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
// Set the Interval to 60 seconds (60000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 60000;
//for enabling for disabling the timer.
aTimer.Enabled = true;
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     //disable the timer
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
 }
```