# C# Visual Studio - Wait 3 seconds and do something at the end of method and kill the timer?

Tags: c#, time, timer, wait

I am writing a "game" simulating Student's Adventures at The University and what I have done already is few forms, still I need one form to not wait for user input but check if I want an Game Event to run now, if not, then wait few seconds and then skip to another day and repeat the procedure for that day.

The thing is user is able to quit the game at any time and all the information is saved so I need to keep it an one-shot timer of few seconds that doesn't run for another time after it expires.

How do I write an one-shot timer or delay an execution of my c# code for few seconds?

EDIT:
MessageBox.Show("I will wait 3 seconds now");
wait 3 seconds
...
after 3 seconds
MessageBox.Show("3 seconds passed since I poped out last message box!");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all that you want to do is create a method to "tick" every so often, there are a few options.

The first would be the System.Threading.Timer object, documented on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

An example of this:

```
public void Tick(object stateInfo /* required to fit TimerCallback signature */)
{
    /// add your code here
}
```

And your Timer instantiation would look like so:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, null, 0, 3000);
```

And thereafter Tick() will be executed every 3 seconds. Feel free to replace the null with an object of your choice so as to keep track of state.

A second, worse choice would be to use a BackgroundWorker. The primary advantage I've found in this is that the ProgressChanged event handler is automatically invoked in the primary UI thread, so you can use it fairly easily for cross-thread code that involves the UI in some sense. Here's the documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I don't think the BackgroundWorker would be a good choice - it's user-friendly, but it's not really designed to persist infinitely, or activate periodically, so its usage leads to bad workarounds like wrapping all the DoWork code in a while(true) loop and using Thread.Sleep() to pause execution.

A third would be the System.Timers.Timer object, which takes an Interval in milliseconds and an Elapsed event hooked into one of your methods. Each time the interval passes, your method is called. The documentation for that is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Note that all of these work slightly differently, so one may well fit your use case significantly better. We can't really tell you which one is best because we don't really know much about your implementation right now.

Comment: I want the Tick Event to happen once after initial 3 seconds and then never again. So in essential I want to delay the execution of my code by 3 seconds in certain place.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - what do you mean by "delay" and by "my code"? Which code do you want to delay, and what function do you want the application to retain during those three seconds?

Comment: Example:
MessageBox.Show("I am gonna wait 3 seconds before I pop another message box!);
...
MessageBox.Show("3 seconds passed!");

I managed to do it with:
public async void Wait(int i)
{
int b=i*1000;
await Task.Delay(b);
}

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Timer tmr = new Timer(S, null, 0, 5000);
                Console.Read();
            }
            static void S(object obj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            }
```

and u can look here
[Execute a method after delay on time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185647/execute-a-method-after-delay-on-time-only)

Comment: Well downvoting cuz I can't find an answer when the topic with it has a quite crucial misspelling is quite cruel. 

I should add it's not a console application but Windows Forms one just in case.

Comment: Answers should include explanation that can stand on its own, not just links (which have a habit of disappearing). Also, the question was posed in English. so if you're going to include a link, please include a link to the English language version of the page.