# TimerCallback not invoked on 1 second delay C#

Tags: c#

I am simply attempting to execute a method after a 1 second delay.
This method should only ever be called once.

I have followed these examples to try to achieve what I want but to no avail:

1. [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185647/execute-a-method-after-delay-on-time-only)
2. [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ah1h85ch.aspx)

My current code:

```
private void NetworkIsActive() {
    // delay to allow the network to properly set firs
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(this.CheckInternetConnection);
    TimeSpan delayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    try {
        Timer updateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, delayTime, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
    } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException Ex) {
        throw Ex;
    } catch (ArgumentNullException NEx) {
        throw NEx;
    } catch (Exception x) {
        throw x;
    }
}
```

**CheckInternetConnection()**

```
private void CheckInternetConnection(object state) {
    switch (NetworkActivities.IsInternetAvailable()) {
        case TRUE:
            this.ExternalIP = NetworkActivities.getExternalIP();
            this.InternetConnection = ACTIVE;
            break;
        case FALSE:
            this.ExternalIP = EMPTY;
            this.InternetConnection = INACTIVE;
            break;
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting the *state* argument to `null` but makes no difference.

`CheckInternetConnection` is never invoked and no exception is thrown in the `try...catch`

I would rather get this way working as I am not in favour of using `Thread.Sleep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timer` isn't self-sustaining - you need to keep a reference to it, or it's going to disappear. Since it's a local in your case, it's eligible for collection before your method even ends.

Comment: Where's the best pace to keep a reference to it? The constructor?

Comment: @wmash The constructor cannot keep a reference, since the constructor is 'temporarily active'.

Comment: @Luaan The timer is not eligible for collection since the class and timer are connected through the callback delegate.

Comment: @Maarten ah yes of course! Where would be best then?

Comment: @wmash A local field in the class would work. But I don't think that is the problem. Check [BugFinder's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38370516/261050).

Comment: @Maarten No, you've got that backwards. If the timer were rooted, the form would be rooted through the delegate. It doesn't work the other way around - that would make garbage collection rather pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a Timer.Start() so your timer wont trigger, you havent started it